# Access continuous forms: record status

Tags: ms-access, vba

When generating new lines in a continuous form, the last line appears with a pen on the record selector (picture 1). Once another record has been clicked, this pen is replaced by an arrow (picture 2).

How can one programmatically identify the 'pen' status versus the 'arrow' status?

[image]

Comment: Check whether the pen symbol is consistent with `Me.Dirty = True`

Comment: Well done ... could you post it as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the pen symbol appears when an edit is in progress for the current record.

Check to confirm the pen symbol's presence is consistent with the form's Dirty status ... if `Me.Dirty = True`, the record selector symbol should be the pencil instead of the arrow.